# JavaFX - Read Java-Class-String in FXML file

Tags: string, javafx, fxml

is there any possibility, that I can access a String Variable from a Java-Class and use the value in my fxml file?

e.g.

Java-Class:

```
public class Strings{
   ...   
   static String MY_STRING = "Hello World!";
   ...    
}
```

FXML-File:

```
...
<Label
   text = Strings.MYSTRING;
   />
...
```

I know how I can do it programmatically, I just want to know if it's also possible this way.

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible via the `fx:constant` attribute, in your case:

```
<Label>
    <text><Strings fx:constant="MYSTRING"/></text>
</Label>
```

The feature was added with JavaFX 2.2: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/whats_new2.htm